# A non-linear system that describes pendulum movement.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Basically, I have this system.

\begin{cases} \dot{x} = y \\ \dot{y} =-\mu y – \text{sin}(x) \end{cases}

This models a pendulum with damping. 
I have found its equilibrium points;

$(0,0),(\pi,0)$ I want to evaluate the stability of these points, so i linearize the system to obtain

\begin{cases} \dot{h_1} = h_2 \\ \dot{h_2} =-\mu h_2 -h_1 \end{cases}

\begin{cases} \dot{h_1} = h_2 \\ \dot{h_2} =-\mu h_2 +h_1 \end{cases}

respectively.

Now for the fun part, I am given the condition that $\mu \in (0,2)$, and I find the eiginvalues to be

$$\lambda = \frac{-\mu \pm \sqrt{\mu^2-4}}{2},\lambda = \frac{-\mu \pm \sqrt{\mu^2+4}}{2} $$ repectively.

The first pair of eiginvalues are what we expect, a complex conjugate pair with negative real part, so a spiral sink. The second pair give one positive real eiginvalue and one negative, this would be a saddle point right? It's a linear approximation to I am not really concerned about the long time result.

But since we are only interested in non negative time, could we label this as a physically unstable point, as this point corresponds to balancing the bob perfectly above the pendulum, so any perturbation would result in it moving away from this point? or am i saying something/doing something silly?

Moving on from this I am now given the conditions that (i) $\mu = 0$

Concerning the equilibrium point(0,0), any perturbation from the equilibrium would result in perpetual motion, or closed contoured motion.
concerning the point $(\pi,0)$ we have exponential growth. for t>0
(ii) $\mu = 2$

Concerning the equilibrium point(0,0), we have a repeated eiginvalue $\lambda = -1$ with corresponding eiginvector (1,1), so the pendulum would not oscillate, it would exhibit critical damping.

and concerning the other equilibrium point, we would have the repeated eiginvector 1. This describes exponential growth.

I am asked to explain why the predictions may not be valid in both cases.

Well in case (i), we have perpetual motion, this is not physically valid, and in case (ii) the bob would return immediately to the origin.

But I feel that the point(\pi,0) still holds, regardless whether we have case (i),(ii).

Could someone point out any holes in my "analysis"?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not surprising that you have a perpetual motion since you put $\mu = 0$, which means you have zero friction, and therefore, no loss or damping. That means the condition $\mu = 0$ is not physically valid, and give you merely a theoretic answer.

This is also true for the case $(0,0)$. Without damping ($\mu = 0$) but $\dot h_2 = -h_1$ an increase in $h_1$ yields larger attraction, independetly of the magnitude of $h_2$.

Your other deviations seems sound.